# How do Sharepoint workflow triggers work?

Tags: workflow

I've been trying to find a good detailed tutorial on sharepoint workflow triggers to understand how workflows start. All I know so far is that there are 3 types of workflow triggers:

- Manually
- On change (automatic)
- On create (automatic)

But, I have no idea what this means actually. What's being changed or created? What's the difference between manual & automatic? I read somewhere that custom actions can also be used as a workflow trigger? But I'm not exactly sure how that works too.

Can someone explain all the triggers and how to create a workflow from them if possible? Or if you have a good article/youtube video on this topic that explains **in detail**, mind sharing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual is basically the user presses a button (like a custom action)
On Change is whenever a user changes anything on the current item
On Create is whenever a user creates a nw item (E.g. in a list or document library)

You can configure workflows on lists and libraries those can be set to any combination of the above. Site workflows - which isn't tied to any lists or libraries - can only be set to start manually.

Comment: Here is a link to MS info on workflows [link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579)  Though it is very detailed.  I checked my favourites but also do not have a good link to a workflow tutorial.  Just to add to what Morten said re: triggers:  On Create = when a new item or document is created the workflow will automatically run; this can be useful to notify people of a new item / task / approval request etc.  On Change = if the item is modified the workflow triggers; useful if e.g. a task is reassigned